# Use jQuery to scroll div horizontally back and forth on loop

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I couldn't find any posts about this Googling suprisingly, I'm making the assumption (probably foolish assumption) that what I need has a simple solution though.

I have a div with child element that has a width wider than the viewport (on mobile), I have overflow-x: scroll on the child element so the horizontal scroll bar appears. I'd like to use jquery to animate the horizontal scroll position of this element so it slowly scrolls from left to right and back again once it reaches the end, ideally looping infinitely.

I kind of don't want to post this because I don't have any jQuery written to contribute, but I'm not sure where to start.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wide_content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wide_content {
    width: 1200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;                            
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an infinite right and left scrolling motion you have can use, for example, the JQuery [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function and an infinite loop :

```js
var scroll = function(width) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: width,
  }, 2000);
};

var loopForever = function(delay, callback) {
  var loop = function() {
    callback();
    setTimeout(loop, delay);
  };
  loop();
};

loopForever(1000, function() {
  scroll($('.wide_content').width());
  scroll(0);
});
```

```css
.wide_content {
  width: 1200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wide_content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I couldn't get it to function properly in my actual project unfortunately, for some reason on smaller screens it doesn't scroll all the way to the right, it stops around 70% of the way and goes back. This is probably related to the fact I can't set a width property on my wide element without my scrollbar becoming empty. The scrollbar only appears if I set the width to auto, anyways thanks for the help.